# Python PyQt5 PushButton not working properly (in certain areas)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I created something similar to a library management system GUI using PyQt5. I created a QScrollArea where my QGroupBoxes are placed using a for loop. Somehow some of the pushbuttons inside my groupboxes are not working properly though in certain areas it works perfectly fine.
It seems like the pushbuttons work properly when inside the first half of the scroll area. Ad when its in the second half if doesn't work at all (I must say, it works just like an image label instead of a pushbutton)

```
    self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
    self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 711, 391))
    self.scroll.setBaseSize(711, 391)
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scroll)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 700, 700))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

    # Just an example so see if the loop works properly
    example_list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
    key = 0 

    for num in example_list: 
        resgroup1 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        # resgroup1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 15, 651, 111))
        resgroup1.setFixedSize(651, 115)
        resgroup1.setMinimumHeight(115)
        resgroup1.setTitle(f"GroupBox #{key}")
        resgroup1.setFlat(True)
        resgroup1.setObjectName("resgroup1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(resgroup1, key, 0)

        res_title1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(resgroup1)
        res_title1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 20, 481, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        res_title1.setFont(font)
        res_title1.setObjectName("res_title1")
        res_title1.setText(f"TITLE #{num}")
        res_auth1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(resgroup1)
        res_auth1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 481, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Rockwell")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        res_auth1.setFont(font)
        res_auth1.setObjectName("res_auth1")
        res_auth1.setText(f"AUTH #{num}")
        
        # This is the PushButton I was talking about (which also acts as the book cover of the books in my library GUI)
        res_cover1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(resgroup1)
        res_cover1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 15, 121, 91))
        res_cover1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("projects/will.jpeg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        res_cover1.setIcon(icon1)
        res_cover1.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(87, 87)) 
        res_cover1.setFlat(True)
        res_cover1.setObjectName("res_cover1")
        # res_cover1.show()
        key += 1


    self.widget.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
```

This is the video of my whole code running. Please focus on my cursor and where is is pointed/clicking to better understand what I am talking about. Thank you in advanced!

[This the video!!!!](https://youtu.be/tEehV-h3cZQ)

P.S. :
I tried using this code to my real python file and the all the QPushButtons (top and bottom half of the scroll area) are now  completely unclickable (not working as a button). It is not doing anything like showing the PointingHandCursor whenever I hover over it not is it clickable. I don't think I did anything to it though except adding it to my real Library Management System Python file

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. For instance, you're creating the grid layout for `gridLayoutWidget`, but then you're setting that layout on `self.widget`, and `gridLayoutWidget` is not even used anywhere else. My impression is that that widget is probably the culprit: even if it's not used, it's still there, and occupies a geometry that match what's shown in the video. Try removing that widget completely, change to `self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)` and remove `self.widget.setLayout(self.gridLayout)`. If it still doesn't work, please [edit] your post and provide a [mre].

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I don't think it worked since all the buttons are still not working and are unclickable.  Later, I'll try to understand what's really happening and edit the code and update this post. Anyways, thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @musicamante I think I figured what the problem was after reading your solution and looking at some google examples of QScrollArea. You were right about the `self.gridLayoutWidget` not having any purpose or not being used anywhere. The main problem was that I created `self.gridLayoutWidget`, and placed `self.gridLayout` in it which was really unnecessary since I don't think I should place the `self.gridLayout` anywhere. And I think the second problem was that I also placed the groupboxes inside `self.gridLayoutWidget`. Thank you, again!!!!!

Comment: You *do* need the grid layout, and it has to be set on `self.widget` as explained above (either by creating it with the widget in the constructor, or by using `setLayout`). The creation of the groupboxes is not a big deal: as soon as you do `addWidget`, ownership is automatically set on the widget that is managed by the layout, so, while it's theoretically an error, the result wouldn't have changed. Obviously, since there won't be any `gridLayoutWidget` at all, there's no point at all: generally speaking, widgets that are being added to a layout can be created without the parent constructor.